# Need to know the date when user joins group in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I'm using Liferay 6.2 ga4.

I need to know the date when user joins some group (in default meaning of Liferay) and storage it in database.

However, there is only `users_groups` default table which I can not expand. What should I do in my situation? Of course, I can create one more entity using ServiceBuilder, but I don't think it's a good idea to duplicate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is no such type of info already in your liferay database, you could write an service wrapper hook and write the date into an expando value.

Comment: That's the way I am considering about too. Thank you, good advice!